# What are the maximum operating temperatures of the components?

Tags: hardware, cooling, temperature

What are the main sources of heat on the board?

What temperatures do these components reach under load?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> [HackADay](http://hackaday.com/2012/06/23/checking-out-the-temperature-of-a-raspberry-pi/) posted a link to [an article](http://www.geektopia.es/es/technology/2012/06/22/articulos/se-calienta-el-ordenador-raspberry-pi-estudio-de-sus-temperaturas-en-funcionamiento.html) (in Spanish - [translated to English](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.geektopia.es/es/technology/2012/06/22/articulos/se-calienta-el-ordenador-raspberry-pi-estudio-de-sus-temperaturas-en-funcionamiento.html&act=url)) with some thermal images, I'll summarise it:

There are three main sources of heat -

1. The input voltage regulator (bottom left).

   This regulates the input down from Vcc to 5V. Assuming this is a linear regulator, power dissipation will equal `P=(Vcc-5)*I`, where `I` is the current usage of the device.

   If you supply the board with 6V, and draw 0.5A, the power dissipated by this chip will be (6-5)*0.5 = 0.5W.
2. SoC BCM2835 (middle). This contains the ARM11 CPU, GPU and RAM.
3. [LAN951](http://www.smsc.com/index.php?tid=328&pid=135) (right). This is the USB/Ethernet controller.

The following tests were performed at an ambient temperature of 26-27°C with no draft.

**Idle - no Ethernet:**

[image: Thermal image at idle]

1. 49.9°C
2. 48.7°C
3. 53.0°C

**Idle - Ethernet connected:**

[image: Thermal image at idle with Ethernet]

3. Ethernet controller temp increases to 55.7°C with a maximum of 59.5°C.

**CPU Stress Test:**

[image: Thermal image with CPU Stress Test]

2. CPU temp increases to 55.7°C with a maximum of 57.9°C.

**High Definition Video Playback:**

[image: Thermal image with HD video playback and Ethernet]

2. CPU/GPU temp increases to 56.1°C with a maximum of 58.6°C.
3. Ethernet controller temp increases to 60.8°C with a maximum of 65.1°C.

**Conclusion**

From the above tests we can conclude that the hottest component is the Ethernet/USB controller, with a maximum of ~65°C (37°C above ambient). The CPU/GPU reaches ~59°C (31°C above ambient), whilst the voltage regulator reaches ~59°C (31°C above ambient).

Comment: It was someone's crazy idea to use a linear regulator, if indeed one is used. These days switchers are tiny and cheap...