# Very high idle temp?

Tags: temperature

My raspberry pi was very slow so I did a temperature measurement and it was 79°C at idle.
This looks very high. Does anyone know what can cause this? Maybe something is broken.
edit: It doesn't want to boot and is stuck in a bootloop now, this is probably because of the temperature.

Comment: You should explain how you determined the pi was "idle".

Comment: Also details on any case, anything connected and what's the environment?  What Pi and how's it powered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the maximum operating temperatures of the components?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/675/what-are-the-maximum-operating-temperatures-of-the-components)

Answer (score 3):

Yes - 79°C is pretty "warm". At that temperature the RPi's [thermal management system](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/frequency-management.md) is likely involved.

***What can cause this?*** Heavy *loading* on the processor can cause it. One way to check for that is using [`top`](https://linoxide.com/monitoring-2/10-tools-monitor-cpu-performance-usage-linux-command-line/) - a command-line utility that's included in all recent RPi OS distributions. The link above and [this one](https://linoxide.com/linux-command/linux-top-command-examples-screenshots/) may help you gather some intelligence about what's going on in your system... once you actually get it to boot!

The boot problem may or may not have anything to do with the thermal throttling. If you've let the RPi sit long enough to reach room temperature, I'd hazard a guess that it's **not** the thermal management system stopping the boot process.

Suggestions for overcoming the boot issue:

- make sure your power supply is operating properly, and if you can, measure the voltage at the RPi input.
- re-flash the OS on a new SD card

Update your question after you've done this & we'll take another look.